# Is there a way to have AWS RDS Public Accessibility = No but still accessible outside of EC2 instance?

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc, rds, aws-security-group

For management-related reasons, I need the Public Accessibility option set to "No" for the RDS.

However, we're also looking into being able to access the RDS from our local devices. The only way we're able to do so is by selecting "Yes" in Public Accessibility. Of course, the VPC, Gateway, Subnet, and Security Groups  are already set with the appropriate public-facing stuff, which is probably why the Yes option is working.

But the moment we set it to No, only the EC2 instances are now able to connect to the database.

Is there a way around this or is that really what the Public Accessibility flag does by design?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should set up a VPN connection to your VPC

Comment: Ah, I completely forgot about that option. I'll see if management is alright with setting up a VPN.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes Public Accessibility flag prevent you from accessing the RDS directly through Internet, but you can indirectly access through a jumpserver(like ssh bashtion) which is placed in public subnet. Most of the popular Mysql UI editors like sequel pro has a in build option for ssh config, using this option you can access RDS from local devices. you can also configure tunneling to bastion.

Answer (score 5):

Setting **Public Accessibility to "No"** will not allow any access from the internet. There are plenty of ways to connect your RDS to your local.

1. Add your public IP in the **security group** of your rds database instance
2. **Jump Server / Bastion**
3. **VPN / Direct Connect**

Your asking for the best approach on how to secure this.. The best option is #3. 
But to do this, you will need to build your database instance in the **private subnet**.

How?

Navigate to RDS > Subnet Groups. 
Create a DB Subnet Group. 
Select your VPC and the private subnet to use.

Comment: Hey,
I have tried the 1st method (add my ip addr to the security group of my rds) but I still have to have Public Accessibility option set to "Yes" to have a connexion from an outside client... Have you personally tried that option ? If yes, do you have more details to share about it?

Also the 3rd option seems interesting, any pointers to some doc/tutorials?

Thanks!

Comment: same, it looks like the first option is not possible if Public Accessibility is set to No

Answer (score 0):

As @user11389395 mentioned, you must have **Public Accessibility** set to "**Yes**" in the RDS "**Modify**" page (this won't cause any outage of your database, or cause it to go down).

Once you have enabled it, you must jump into the **Security Group** that your RDS server is on, add an **Inbound** rule with the **TCP Protocol**, port **3306** (if using MySQL), and then in the **Source** dropdown, select "**My IP**":

[image: AWS Security Group Inbound Rules]

When you select "My IP", you should see the source input field gray out and display your public IP address. You can confirm this public IP address by checking it online through Google. This grants only **your** public IP address access to your RDS database through the internet.

Once you save the rule, you should then be able to connect using TablePlus (or another SQL client) from your local computer by entering your RDS "**Endpoint**" (shown on the RDS "**Connectivity and Security**" tab) as the **hostname**, and your master username and password.